# Very slow (12+ hours) large table joins in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

I am struggling to optimize a simple `LEFT JOIN` against two very large tables that so far has been taking > 12 hours to complete and ongoing.

Here is the execution plan:

```
Gather  (cost=1001.26..11864143.06 rows=8972234 width=133)
  Workers Planned: 7
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.26..10773657.51 rows=1281748 width=133)
        ->  Parallel Index Scan using var_case_aliquot_aliquot_ind on var_case_aliquot vca  (cost=0.56..464070.21 rows=1281748 width=103)
        ->  Index Scan using genotype_pos_ind on snv_genotypes gt  (cost=0.70..8.01 rows=1 width=65)
              Index Cond: ((vca.chrom = chrom) AND (vca.start = start) AND (vca.end = end) AND ((vca.alt)::text = (alt)::text))
              Filter: (vca.aliquot_barcode = aliquot_barcode)
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT vca.aliquot_barcode,
    vca.case_barcode,
    vca.gene_symbol,
    vca.variant_classification,
    vca.variant_type,
    vca.chrom,
    int4range(vca.start::integer, vca."end"::integer, '[]'::text) AS pos,
    vca.alt,
    gt.called AS mutect2_call,
    gt.ref_count,
    gt.alt_count,
    gt.read_depth,
    gt.called OR
        CASE
            WHEN (gt.alt_count + gt.ref_count) > 0 THEN (gt.alt_count::numeric / (gt.alt_count + gt.ref_count)::numeric) > 0.20
            ELSE false
        END AS vaf_corrected_call
   FROM analysis.var_case_aliquot vca
     LEFT JOIN analysis.snv_genotypes gt ON vca.aliquot_barcode = gt.aliquot_barcode AND vca.chrom = gt.chrom AND vca.start = gt.start AND vca."end" = gt."end" AND vca.alt::text = gt.alt::text
```

Both tables are very large: `vca` and `gt` have 9 million (2 GB) and 1.3 billion rows (346 GB), respectively.

I created the `vca` (`MATERIALIZED VIEW`) for the sole purpose of performing this join. Essentially it's a join table with only the required fields for a 1:1 matching left join and then some extra metadata. All the fields being joined on are properly indexed as you can see from the query plan.

The query itself is simple enough, is there something I'm missing that could speed it up? I don't suppose there is some way to use `WHERE` instead?

Is there something I can tweak in my postgres settings that might help? Currently I have the following:

```
shared_buffers = 4096MB
effective_cache_size = 20GB
work_mem = 64MB
maintenance_work_mem = 4096MB
max_wal_size = 4GB
min_wal_size = 128MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
max_worker_processes = 16
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 8
max_parallel_workers = 16
```

UPDATE 12/12:

Table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE analysis.snv_genotypes (
    aliquot_barcode character(30) NOT NULL,
    chrom character(2) NOT NULL,
    start bigint NOT NULL,
    "end" bigint NOT NULL,
    alt character varying(510) NOT NULL,
    genotype character(3),
    read_depth integer,
    ref_count integer,
    alt_count integer,
    called boolean
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY analysis.snv_genotypes
    ADD CONSTRAINT genotype_pk PRIMARY KEY (aliquot_barcode, chrom, start, "end", alt);
CREATE INDEX called_ind ON analysis.snv_genotypes USING btree (called);
CREATE INDEX genotype_pos_ind ON analysis.snv_genotypes USING btree (chrom, start, "end", alt);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW analysis.var_case_aliquot AS
 SELECT var_case_aliquot.aliquot_barcode,
    var_case_aliquot.case_barcode,
    var_case_aliquot.chrom,
    var_case_aliquot.start,
    var_case_aliquot."end",
    var_case_aliquot.alt,
    var_case_aliquot.gene_symbol,
    var_case_aliquot.variant_classification,
    var_case_aliquot.variant_type,
    var_case_aliquot.hgvs_p,
    var_case_aliquot.polyphen,
    var_case_aliquot.sift
   FROM var_case_aliquot
  WITH NO DATA;

CREATE INDEX var_case_aliquot_aliquot_ind ON analysis.var_case_aliquot USING btree (aliquot_barcode);
CREATE INDEX var_case_aliquot_pos_ind ON analysis.var_case_aliquot USING btree (chrom, start, "end", alt);
```

More extensive DDL here: https://rextester.com/JRJH43442

UPDATE 12/13:

To clarify, I am using Postgres 10.5 on CentOS 7.3 w/ 16 cores and 32 GB mem. The query has now been running for 24+ hrs without any result.

Checking on the status it seems that `wait_event_type` is `IO`. Does this mean the query is scratching/writing to scratch space? Could this explain the slowness?

```
+------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+--------+-------------+--------------+
| application_name | backend_start | xact_start    | query_start   | state_change  | wait_event_type | wait_event   | state  | backend_xid | backend_xmin |
+------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+--------+-------------+--------------+
| psql             | 12/12/18 8:42 | 12/12/18 8:42 | 12/12/18 8:42 | 12/12/18 8:42 | IO              | DataFileRead | active | 22135       | 22135        |
+------------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+--------------+--------+-------------+--------------+
```

I have a lot of available resources:

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        722M        210M        5.0G         30G         25G
Swap:          3.7G        626M        3.1G
```

I guess making more memory available could help? Is there some way to optimize queries that need more memory than available to them?

Comment: What postgresql version do you use and can you show ddl table? I am suggesting you post to [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will do that. I'm using postgres 10.5. I'll update the post with DDL.

Comment: Added the DDL here https://rextester.com/JRJH43442

Comment: Please put relevant code eg DDL in your post, make it self-contained. [mcve]

Comment: Do you have 8 cores at your disposal? Does it change anything if you crank up `work_mem` to 1GB temporarily?

Comment: @philipxy I updated my post.
@LaurenzAlbe I have 16 cores and 32 GB of mem at my disposal, running postgres 10.5 on Centos 7.3. I could get a better system if that would improve the query?

P.s. the query has been running for > 24 hrs now and no idea what the status is, is there a chance it has died? This is not the first time I've tried to run this query, most other times I ended up killing it after ~12 hrs so this is the longest I have had it running. All other queries work fine, but there is an `AccessShareLock` on both input tables.

Comment: 1st question: How big are the "alt" fields in average ? maybe building the result is what's taking up so much time. 2nd question: Have you tried reducing the number of fields displayed for testing ? like for example: only select "aliquot_barcode". 3rd Question: are you sure it's a 1:1 relationship ? You mean every record in vca has an equivalent in gt ?

Comment: @Asoub (1) on average they are length 1, only in very rare occasion are they larger (max is 134). (2) I have not tried this, but I've tried using `LIMIT` and eg. `LIMIT 100` finishes in < 1s, `LIMIT 200` ~ 7s, `LIMIT 500` ~ 9s, `LIMIT 1000` ~27s (3) There may be a few occasions where a record in VCA does not have a record in GT (i'd say less than 0.0001% of records, if at all), but every record in VCA will have at most 1 record and never more in GT.

Comment: what is `analysis.snv_genotypes.alt` ? what does it mean ? why is it part of the composite key ? Why are `barcode` **plus** the {chrom, start,end} part of the key? [ I think this really should be a *junction* table, linking samples to sample-contents; maybe even via *two* extra tables]

Comment: @joop, the `alt` defines the variant, you can have multiple records at the same {chrom,start,end} with different `alt` (alternative alleles). Either way, thanks @everyone for the suggestion, I will accept @Asoub's answer, but I think what I learned here today is that the system I was working on was not powerful enough to deal with the large amount of data that I had. No parallel support for writes in PG10.5 also did not help, so I will upgrade the system (esp. the disks because I was getting a lot of swapping and %iowait > 40) and PG10 > PG11.

Comment: So, basically `alt` is a (large) low-cardinality column, and part of a composite key. Maybe you should reconsider your data model. (are there *really* multiple `alt` values for the *same* {barcode,chrom,start,end} ?

Comment: Yes there are! For 90-95% of the rows the `alt` column is a character of length 1, one of four DNA nucleotides (C/T/A/G). For each {barcode,chrom,start,end} you can have an alt that is any one of those. Some indel variants (far less common) have long alts up to hundreds of nucleotides long, but these make up < 5% of the data.

Comment: Strong advice: please study some normalisation while the query is running. Your tables are not in 3NF. Extra question: how many *distinct* sets of {chrom,start,end} do there exist ? (maybe with/without alt or genotype)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I don't know what that is but I will search. There are ~2.703 mln {chrom,start,end,alt} combos (stored in table of snvs), of which 2.701 mln have DISTINCT {chrom,start,end}. There are ~800 {barcodes} (stored in table w/ barcodes), so there's a theoretical maximum of 800x2.703mln combinations, of which there are 1.3 billion in the snv_genotypes table.

Comment: In short: denormalisation (into a materialized view) does *not* speed up your query. It only increases the volume of data to be read/witten from/to disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this post's comment:

> Your query is using `genotype_pos_ind`and filtering on `aliquot_barcode`. Try deleting (temporarly) `genotype_pos_ind` and if that doesn't work, search how to force index usage.

Your query should be using `genotype_pk` instead.

From what you said, there might be a lot of record with the same values for `aliquot_barcode`, `chrom`, `start` and `end`, so the RDBMS will then take a long time to filter every `aliquot_barcode`.

And if it's still too long for you, you can try my older answer, which I'll keep for further references:

---

---

<s>Unfortunately, I won't ba able to optimize your query: there is too much things to take into account. Building a result with 9 millions record of 13 fields might be too much: swapping might occur, your OS won't allow so much memory allocation, while also making `JOIN`, etc..</s>   (writtent before the real answer...)

I used to optimize some query consisting of fifteen table of around 10 millions records. `SELECT` of this size would never be doable in reasonable time (less than 10 hours).

I don't have any RDBMS to test what I'm saying. Also, I haven't done any SQL for half a year :p 
Finding why this is taking so much time (as you asked) will be too much time consumming, so here is another solution to the original problem.

---

The solution I adopted was making temporary table:

1. Create the temporary table: `tmp_analysis`, with the same fields as your `SELECT` + some utility fields:

An ID field (`tmp_ID`, a big int), a boolean to check if record has been updated (tmp_updated), and timestamp to check when it has been updated (`tmp_update_time`).
And of course all fields, with the same datatypes, from your original `SELECT` (from `vca` and `gt`)

2. Insert all your records from `vca`:

Use `null` (or any other default value if you can't) for fields from `gt` for the moment. Set `tmp_updated` to false. Use a simple `count()` for the primary key.

3. Update all these records with fields from gt.

Use a `WHERE` rather than a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE tmp_analysis as tmp -- I don't think you need to use a schema to call tmp_analysis
    SET tmp_update = true,
    tmp_update_time = clock_timestamp(),
    tmp.mutect2_call = gt.called
    gt.ref_count,
    gt.alt_count,
    gt.read_depth,
    gt.called = -- ... (your CASE/WHEN/ELSE/END should work here)
FROM 
    analysis.snv_genotypes gt
WHERE --JOIN should work too
    tmp.aliquot_barcode = gt.aliquot_barcode AND 
    tmp.chrom = gt.chrom AND 
    vca.start = gt.start AND 
    tmp."end" = gt."end" AND 
    tmp.alt::text = gt.alt::text
```

I said that you should use `EXISTS` for performance reasons, but I was mistaken as I don't think you can retreive fields from inside the `EXISTS` condition. There might be a way to tell Postgresql that it's a one to one relationship, but I'm not sure. Anyway, index

4. Obviously, `SELECT` your `tmp_analysis` table to get your records !

---

Some notes for this:

1. If it's taking too much time:

Use the `tmp_ID` field to limit the number of update to 10 000 for example and check the execution plan of the 3rd query (`UPDATE`): You should have a full scan on the temporary table table and an index scan on `gt` (on `genotype_pk`). If not, check your indexes and search how to force index use by PGSL. You should use `WHERE tmp_ID < 10000` rather than `LIMIT 10000`. IIRC, `LIMIT` will execute the whole query and just give you part of the result.

2. If it's still taking too much time:

Segment the query using `tmp_ID` and (as you said) use a [loop statement](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-loop-statements/) on the `UPDATE` to query with 100 000 or less records at once (again, use `where tmp_ID < x AND tmp_ID > y`). Check the execution plan again: the full scan should be limited by the `tmp_id` before the index scan. Don't forger to add an index on this fild (if it's not already the primary key).

3. If you need to call this again later:

Use `BEGIN/END TRANSACTION` to encapsulate all the queries, and the `TEMPORARY TABLE` option on `CREATE TABLE tmp_analysis` so that you won't have to clean tmp_analysis after executing the query.

4. If you still have a problem with loops:

Use transactions inside the loop, and stop it if it freezes again. Then you can restore it later with a smaller loop size.

5. If you want to reduce a little bit the execution time:

You can do step 1 and 2 in one query with a `INSERT .. AS .. SELECT`, but I don't remember how to set datatype for fields from `gt`, as they'll be set to null. Normally, this should be a little bit faster as a whole.

6. If you're curious:

And the query without the loop still takes more than 10 hours, stop it and checks the tmp_update_time to see how execution times evolves, maybe it'll give you a clue about why the original query didn't worked. There are multiple configuration options on PGSQL to limit RAM usage, disk usage, threads. Your OS might put it's own limits, and check disk swapping, CPU cache usage, etc. (I think you've already done some of this but I didn't check)

Comment: Actually, I've tried running the query separately for a handful of `case_barcodes` (using `WHERE case_barcode = XX`) and the results are given in no more than a minute or two. It would perfect sense to me if there was some way to loop across each of `case_barcode` and perform a new query for each, printing the result to a table or something?

Comment: Also, can you add an example of how I would do part (3) in your suggested solution? Would I loop over rows in groups, or row by row? And how can I make a loop in postgres? P.s. I've since tried this to eliminate the join, but its even slower: `SELECT * FROM analysis.snv_genotypes gt WHERE gt.aliquot_barcode || gt.chrom || gt.start || gt.alt::text IN (SELECT aliquot_barcode || chrom || start || "end" || alt FROM analysis.var_case_aliquot LIMIT 10)`

Comment: @Floris Yes I'm gonna add some detail. Normally, this should work without segmenting the query, but I'll add it too.

Comment: @Floris it's done. About your select in the comment, I thin using "||" (I've never seen this) will create an array, and prevent usage of your indexes.

Comment: yeah the `||` was a pretty dumb idea, it makes everything slower rather than faster! Thanks for your suggestions, I've accepted this answer and I think will have to upgrade the system I am working with in the end.

Comment: @Floris I'm sorry I didn't see that sooner, but your query is using "genotype_pos_ind" and filtering on aliquot_barcode. It should use genotype_pk alone. Try deleting (temporarly) genotype_pos_ind and if that doesn't work, search how to force index usage. Also try to copy just vca in a real table (use "create table as select" syntax) rather than a materialized view, and then try your query with it. Having more powerfull system might not help you if you have a o(n^3) complexity (that's juste an example).

Comment: Thank you for this, very helpful. I was wondering about this myself, but I figured maybe it figured out it how to parallelize using the barcode as strata and that's why its included as a filter? I think there's some room for system improvement especially in the disks/IO because I found out they are real crappy with a write speed of ~150mbps.

Comment: Hey @asoub you were right about the `genotype_pos_ind` and `genotype_pk`! So I first move the entire dataset to a much more powerful system, and ran the query there and after another 12 hours nothing happens. Then I stumbled upon this post: https://medium.com/flatiron-engineering/solving-a-postgres-performance-mystery-51544ceea584 which when reading it described the same situation that you pointed out with `genotype_pos_ind` being used instead of the `genotype_pk` index. After removing `genotype_pos_ind`, the query finished within a hour. Thanks for the help. Do you want to update your answer?

Comment: @Floris I'm glad I could help you ! Though I feel stupid I didn't read more carefully your question the first time .. I'm gonna update my answer and put what solved it on top.

Comment: No problem and thanks! Hopefully it helps other people, I'll keep this in mind in the future to always double check the correct indexes are being used (in the correct order!) when queries are giving issues.